URL in iOS app to open in popup window for login
I'm having an issue where I can't get just a specific url to open in a popup window just for login purposes. The app I have is a webview app.
Here is the code below:
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebPopupViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var urlString: String? // The URL to load in the popup
    @IBOutlet var viewWeb: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupWebView()
        loadURL()
        setupCloseButton()
    }
    
    // Set up the WKWebView to fill the view
    private func setupWebView() {
        viewWeb = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        viewWeb.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(viewWeb)
    }
    
    // Load the URL passed to the view controller
    private func loadURL() {
        guard let urlString = urlString, let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Invalid URL provided to WebPopupViewController")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        viewWeb.load(request)
    }
    
    // Set up a close button to dismiss the popup
    private func setupCloseButton() {
        let closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 50, width: 80, height: 40)) // Position and size as needed
        closeButton.setTitle("Close", for: .normal)
        closeButton.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            closeButton.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closePopup), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        view.addSubview(closeButton)
    }
    
    // Close the popup when the button is tapped
    @objc private func closePopup() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

I can share the project if someone has an idea on what's wrong with it.
TIA
Update: ok so i purchased this source code for a web2app ios app.
Source: https://codecanyon.net/item/rocketweb-configurable-ios-webview-app-template/26369602
im using a booking service, fieldd.co to have my customers schedule appointments.
so in the booking app the users can login via apple or google. the google one is working fine, thee google one isnt.
when the link is clicked, it loads this url first,
https://refresh-158805.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=AIzaSyBcvAPYHf_4w2DnIgc_gceEIHUqsrq6i4E&appName=[DEFAULT]&authType=signInViaPopup&redirectUrl=https://modifiedbenz.fieldd.co/login&v=9.9.3&eventId=0070258736&providerId=google.com&scopes=profile
and then redirects to the google auth. it loads inside the webview and google blocks the access if it loads in popup it will work.
ive tried all i can to get it to work but to no avail...
if anyone can please help me figure this out, o would greatly appreciate it.

What exactly is wrong with it? Please provide your question with descriptions of expected and actual behaviour. Also, it would be great to limit code snippets to bare minimum and remove irrelevant pieces.

What is happening exactly? What are the log saying?

Not sure, what you are trying to accomplish, but you mentioned "login", "popup" and "URL", so iff you want to perform some kind of login executed on a web service, you might look at ASWebAuthenticationSession in the AuthenticationServices framework. See also: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession

i've updated the posted.

I fear, you can't expect much help here, since apparently the package you bought is closed source and no further information is available in the Internet, except many suspicious selling sites and poorly made YT vids, which only show how to install it. On top of this, the vendors web site is not even secure. You'd better off learning either native development, or alternatively Flutter, or one of the many Web based application frameworks. Each are free and open source where you can get great help from many developers.

how would it be done in flutter ?
